# Iterate through an Array of Lists?

Tags: java

In my class, I have an array of `MultipartFile` Lists.

```
public List<MultipartFile>[] attachments;
```

But when I try this:

```
for(List<MultipartFile> mpFiles : attachments[index]) { // <--- Error here
    ........
}
```

I receive the following error:

> `Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type MultipartFile to List

What can I do?

Comment: You are using *foreach* syntax. `attachemets[index]` gives you a list and the elements in that list will be of type `MultipartFile` not `List<MultipartFile>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`attachments` is an array of lists, where each list holds instances of `MultipartFile`.

`attachments[index]` will return `List<MultipartFile>`. If you wish to loop through all the files, the `for` loop would become the following:

```
for(List<MultipartFile> mpFiles : attachments) {
    for(MultipartFile mpf : mpFiles) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When using the for each syntax, you are basically saying *for each x in x's*
In your case, you would need to write the following if we consider `attachments[index]` being a list of `MultipartFile`

```
for(MultipartFile mpFile: attachments[index])
 ...
```

What you seem to be looking for is

```
for(MultipartFile mpFile: attachments)
 ...
```

which iterates through every `MultipartFile` in your list.

Answer (score 0):

`attachments[index]` returns

```
List<MultipartFile>
```

And the result code should be:

```
for(MultipartFile mFile : attachments[index]) { 
  ........
}
```